# Twython filters track and follow

Tags: python, twitter-streaming-api, twython

i need obtain tweets in real time with filters and certain accounts. I try with this:

```
filtro="messi,copa100,copaamierica"
personas="488916863,3034605958" #twitters ids here
stream.statuses.filter(track=filtro, follow=[personas])
```

but only use the track filter, not the follow filter.

Anybody help me with this?
Thanks!!
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using [`filter`](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) method wrongly. It should be:

```
filtro= ["messi", "copa100", "copaamierica"]   # Exact matching of keywords
personas= ["488916863", "3034605958"]      # Comma-separated User ids 
stream.statuses.filter(track = filtro, follow = personas)
```

Comment: +1 Nicklil !! i try with this: `filtro="['messi','copa100','copaamierica']"`
`personas="488916863,3034605958"`
`stream.statuses.filter(track = filtro, follow = personas)`
and works fine!!

Comment: @CarboneroManya, You are still doing it the wrong way. The `follow` parameter takes a list of comma separated user-id's and you must not enclose `filtro` with double-quotes.